# trouble passing string to json python dict

Tags: python

I have the following string, I collected from twitter streaming api

```
"""{"created_at":"Mon Mar 11 20:15:36 +0000 2013","id":311208808837951488,"id_str":"311208808837951488","text":"ALIENS ENTRATE E' IMPORTANTE!!! \n\n\n\nMTV's Musical March Madness ritorna il 18 marzo...Siete pronti A http:\/\/t.co\/ABXEfquTJw via @Hopee_dream","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1025970793,"id_str":"1025970793","name":"Tom's Perfection\u2665","screen_name":"_MyGreenEyes_","location":"","url":null,"description":"Angel,don't you cry,i'll meet you on the other side.\u2661","protected":false,"followers_count":387,"friends_count":520,"listed_count":1,"created_at":"Fri Dec 21 08:39:17 +0000 2012","favourites_count":174,"utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":772,"lang":"it","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3363059730\/3d791e51eefa800150cd99917abc1d2c_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3363059730\/3d791e51eefa800150cd99917abc1d2c_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1025970793\/1362500832","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/ABXEfquTJw","expanded_url":"http:\/\/tl.gd\/l9f5j7","display_url":"tl.gd\/l9f5j7","indices":[101,123]}],"user_mentions":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"medium"}"""
```

I am doing the following operations:

```
import json
json_string = json_string.strip()
jsn_dict = json.loads(json_string)
print jsn_dict["text"]
```

gives:

```
ALIENS ENTRATE E' IMPORTANTE!!!
```

instead of:

```
"ALIENS ENTRATE E' IMPORTANTE!!! \n\n\n\nMTV's Musical March Madness ritorna il 18 marzo...Siete pronti A http:\/\/t.co\/ABXEfquTJw via @Hopee_dream"
```

Looks to me that the newline characters are creating problems in parsing this string to python dictionary.

But then I am doing json_string.strip() operation. I thought it will remove such stuff from my string..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't find any way to reproduce this behavior, with either Python 2.7 or 3.3. If I write `json_string = """…"""` with your triple-quoted string, the `loads` will fail because it's illegal to have a literal newline in a JSON sring. But if I write `json_string = r"""…"""`, it works, and prints exactly the output you want. It prints a bunch of newlines in the middle, of course, but it doesn't truncate the string. I tried every other variation I could think of, in both 2.7 and 3.3, and none of them have the problem you describe. Can you show some actual code that does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `str.strip()` method only removes whitespace characters at the beginning and the end of a string. Not anywhere in the middle.

To remove all newlines from a string, you could do:

```
"some\n\n\nstring".replace("\n", "")
```

or

```
"some\n\n\nstring".translate(None, "\n")
```

The first one is probably easier to read and understand.

Comment: it still doesnt solves the issue in hand?? what about multiple "\n\n\n" clubbed together?

Comment: @Fraz Test it and it should work. Even if there are a bunch clumped together, all such instances will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with text being truncated after the `\n` symbol.

In my case, the issue was because I had accidentally prepended the `#` symbol to the key I was using to pull the value out of the dict:

```
print jsn_dict['#text']
```